# How to make the stored procedure run faster without using several SPs with different names instead of 1?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with all the fields of a table as input values as following. By sending any of items and letting other input items NULL from application, we can get the required data.

```
ALTER procedure [APP].[CRM_Action_Select]
    @ID int = null ,
    @DashbordRefrenceID int = null ,
    @Refrence int = null ,
    @Description NVARCHAR(max) = null ,
    @AttemptCode UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = null ,
    @AttemptName NVARCHAR(100),
    @OrgAttemptCode INT = null ,
    @OrgAttemptName NVARCHAR(100) = null ,
    @OP_CheckerCode UNIQUEIDENTIFIER =NULL,
    @OP_CheckerName NVARCHAR(100)=NULL,
    @Org_ChekerCode INT=NULL,
    @Org_ChekerName NVARCHAR(100)=NULL,
    @ActionDate VARCHAR(50)=NULL,
    @CheckDate VARCHAR(50)=NULL,
    @ActionDescription NVARCHAR(max),
    @RealyAction int = null,
    @IsRead int = null
as
begin
        select *
        from [app].[CRM_Action] with(nolock)
        where
             (@ID is null or ID = @ID) and
             (@DashbordRefrenceID is null or DashbordRefrenceID = @DashbordRefrenceID) AND
             (@Refrence is null or Refrence = @Refrence) and
             (@Description is null or Description = @Description) and
             (@AttemptCode is null or AttemptCode = @AttemptCode) and
             (@AttemptName is null or AttemptName = @AttemptName) AND
             (@OrgAttemptCode is null or OrgAttemptCode = @OrgAttemptCode) and
             (@OrgAttemptName is null or OrgAttemptName = @OrgAttemptName) and
             (@OP_CheckerCode is null or OP_CheckerCode = @OP_CheckerCode) and
             (@OP_CheckerName is null or OP_CheckerName = @OP_CheckerName) and
             (@Org_ChekerCode is null or Org_ChekerCode = @Org_ChekerCode) AND
             (@Org_ChekerName is null or Org_ChekerName = @Org_ChekerName) and
             (@ActionDate is null or ActionDate = @ActionDate) and
             (@CheckDate is null or CheckDate = @CheckDate) and
             (@ActionDescription is null or @ActionDescription = @ActionDescription) and
             (@RealyAction is null or RealyAction = @RealyAction) and
             (@IsRead is null or IsRead = @IsRead)   
        order by ID 
end
```

The problem is as the table grows this procedure slows down. By making other procedures, I found out that checking the `IS NULL` condition in big tables makes it slow down.

I searched for overloading stored procedures, but it seems it is not possible in SQL Server.

Is there any solution for this without having several stored procedures with different names?

Comment: You're never checking the table for null - you're checking your parameters which is the right thing to do. If this is slowing down its because your table is not properly indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ideal candidate for the query hint `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, which will take into account the actual values of the parameters rather than create an execution plan for any possible parameter.

If the actual values are taken into account, the execution plan can eliminate the parts that should not be evaluated. E.g. if `@ID` is in fact NULL, that condition can be removed. That is because `(TRUE OR X)` is always `TRUE`, and in a series of conditions in the style of `X AND Y AND Z ...`, if X is `TRUE` this is equivalent to `Y AND Z ...`.

At the end of the query, add the following:

```
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

---

See [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I added this part and it worked, 30s of response time turned into 3 seconds.
But when I tried this on another table it the 10 seconds response time turned into 12 seconds. 
Does this mean that the OPTION(RECOMPILE) has a load on the dbms and the worth of it depends on the situation ?

Comment: @hadiardebili Recompiling is a cost, but wouldn't take more than a fraction of a second. It's only in queries that are run very frequent (e.g. multiple times per second) that this cost would be undesirable. Option recompile is only suited for some queries, like the one in your question. Also, maybe the other query you mention just returns a lot of rows so that it takes longer to transmit the rows? Without seeing the query, I can't tell you exactly why it is taking longer. Perhaps you should ask a new question if you're stuck on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a dynamic query by setting a base query and extending content based on parameters specified:

```
@Query = 'select * from [app].[CRM_Action] with(nolock)'

IF (@Id IS NOT NULL)
@Query += ' WHERE Id = @Id '

IF (@DashbordRefrenceID IS NOT NULL)
@Query += ' AND DashbordRefrenceID = @DashbordRefrenceID '

IF (@Description IS NOT NULL)
@Query += ' AND Description = @Description '
```

At the end only execute @Query:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```